# Cannot manually Instantiate class inside Component annotated class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am in the process of understanding the Spring and I stumbled with these peculiar things.

I Have the Component annotated class below named MyComponent (please disregard the interface), and that Class uses the `HelperClass`. This helper class was instantiated manually twice for two different variables inside the method named `doSomething`

I also have my bean `project-properties.xml` that was also imported in `app-config.xml`

Yes, there is a Bean for HelperClass for some reason and it also has an Initial value every time it's been @autowired, and even if it is instantiated it manually and that value is from the bean xml.

```java
@Component
public MyCompontent implement MyInterface {
    public doSomething() {
        HelperClass helper1 = new HelperClass();
        HelperClass helper2 = new HelperClass();
        
        
        // print the value set by helper1 and its not null, the value is from bean xml
        System.out.println(helper1.getVariable1);

         
        helper1.setVariable1("Set Value for Helper1");
        helper2.setVariable1("Set Value for Helper2");
        
        // print the value set by helper1 but it display the value of the helper 2
        System.out.println(helper1.getVariable1);
    }


}
```

```java
public HelperClass {

    private String variable1;
    private String variable2;

    public void variable1(String variable1){
        this.variable1 = variable1
    }
    public String getvariable1() {
        return this.variable1;
    }

    
    public void variable2(String variable2){
        this.variable2 = variable2
    }
    public String getvariable2() {
        return this.variable2;
    }
}
```

project-properties.xml

```xml
<beans
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean id="myHelper" class="com.example.HelperClass">
        <property name="variable1" value="bean-value1"/>
        <property name="variable1" value="bean-value2"/>
    </bean>
    
</beans>
```

app-config.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

...........

    <!-- Configures Spring MVC -->
    <import resource="project-properties.xml"/>
    .....
    .....
</beans>
```

My Questions are:

1. I understand that if I use @autowired on HelperClass it will have properties values from bean's XML, but why is it still happening even if I manually Instantiate this class(`HelperClass helper = new HelperClass()`)?
2. What is the mechanism of spring behind this?
3. Can I disable this thing or prevent it to happen in a specific class?
4. Even if I instantiated it multiple times, why are they still pointing or referencing into a Single instance of HelperClass? It sounds like its scope is Singleton.
5. If I ever get the answer to previous questions, my next question is how can I perfectly instantiate HelperClass without reference to the bean, what I mean is how can I disable those things to happen on a specific line in a class?

If you feel that my question is redundant please help me to redirect

Thanks and Regards

Comment: It doesn't. So actually what you describe doesn't make sense. Unless you used `@Configurable` with the proper AspectJ agent to run your application, however I doubt this. So I doubt the code you have shown here is the code you are actually using. I suspect you are missing some `static` keywords in the code shown here.

Comment: Im so stupid, I did not  see that static, thanks!! I  notice the code  yesterday Sorry for this  :D

Answer (score 0):

There is a very high probability that you have been misled by your printings.
Spring can autowire dependencies if class has such annotation on constructor, field, or setter. Spring does not control the instances that have been created manually.

Spring can't even get inside your method, because the framework (in standard case) operates with the interface of your class using reflections. On startup, the framework goes through all the classes, finds all the annotations that have to be processed, and covers such classes with proxies (almost always). But Spring never goes inside your code directly, it can't put a new line of its code in between of 2 your lines in the same method.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, my bad, I did not  see that I put static on variables, this is really embarasing